# Split string into overlapping parts

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have String like this:

```
String s = "1234567890";
```

I'd like use split("regex") to get this output:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
```

What regex should I use?

Comment: use `substring(from, to)` in a loop instead of regex...

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
*“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”*   Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 10):

### This is not an appropriate problem to solve with a regular expression

When there is a much easier and simpler way to solve the problem and most importantly
**more obvious** and self documenting way to do it.

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final String s = "1234567890";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s.substring(i,i+2));
    }
}

12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   *“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”*   Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: you could have easily fixed the one off error and helped everyone out

Comment: I could have. But, as I always tell users with less rep., one should code in an IDE and paste it here to avoid syntax and other obvious errors. This code could have easily been run and checked for correctness for the given problem.

Comment: Why isn't this an appropriate question to solve with regular expressions?  You don't explain why, and it's not obvious... at least not for me

Comment: the explanation is in the answer *"When there is a much easier and simpler way to solve the problem."*

Comment: The regex is simple "(?=(\\d{2}))", and the code isn't longer. So how is it simpler or easier?  I guess it just seems very subjective

Answer (score 10):

<sub>I agree with [Jarrods answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16876512/1393766), if you don't have to use regex and there are other easy solutions then try to avoid regex. But in case you have to use it read rest of my answer...</sub>

Unfortunately you wont be able to do it with `split`, because you want to use same digit in few split parts which is impossible, because split cant add new content to data.

You can do it with look-ahead mechanism

```
String data = "1234567890";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\d\\d))").matcher(data);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

output:

```
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
```

Comment: +1, renamed question to `Split string into overlapping parts` so it have a better chance of getting found. :)